# How to use Swift Mailer in Command

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I have this code...

```
namespace AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;

class NotificationCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('app:notif');
    }

    public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setFrom([
                'from@example.com' => 'Example'
            ])
            ->setTo('to@example.com')
            ->setSubject('Subject')
            ->setBody(
                $this->getContainer()->renderView(
                    'emails/notify.html.twig', [
                        'foo' => 'bar',
                    ]
                ),
                'text/html'
            );

        $this->getContainer()->get('mailer')->send($message);
    }
}
```

And I get an error in response

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "renderView" of class
>   "ContainerV5drzta\appDevDebugProjectContainer".

How do I use Swift Mailer in my Command (Symfony 3.4)?

Comment: your current problem is NOT swiftmailer but the `renderView` you want to call on the container. probably `$this->getContainer()->get('twig')->renderView(...)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can dependency inject these services that should solve the problem and it's also the way Symfony is trying to turn towards.

```
public function __construct(
    EngineInterface $templating,
    \Swift_Mailer $mailer,
) {
    $this->templating = $templating;
    $this->mailer = $mailer;

    parent::__construct();
}
```

You can now in your `execute()` render a template like so:

```
$message = (new \Swift_Message('My message'))
    ->setFrom('foo@bar.com')
    ->setTo('bar@foo.com')
    ->setBody($this->templating->render('mytemplate.html.twig'), 'text/html');

$this->mailer->send($message);
```

You can read more about dependency injecting in Symfony [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html) or a more generic article [here](https://phptherightway.com/#dependency_injection).